# Header line length not long enough

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I used `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` for headers in my work but I noticed that the length of the header line is not the same width as the body of my work.

This is what it looks like

[image: short header length]

This is the preamble of my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,blindtext}

\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{%
\vspace{-8pt}\hrulefill
\raisebox{-2.1pt}{\quad\decofourleft\decotwo\decofourright\quad}\hrulefill}
\title{Decorative line}
\author{Overleaf}
\date{August 2022}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead{\nouppercase{\rightmark\hfill\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot{\hfill\thepage\hfill}


\usepackage[margin=1.0in, headheight=30pt]{geometry} 
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}
\newtheorem{mytherm}{Theorem}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0.1}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codeblue}{rgb}{0.10,0.00,1.00}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{codeblue},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                        
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2,
    frame=none
}
\lstset{style=mystyle}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{abbrv}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[abbrv,1]{label=,labelwidth=1in,align=parleft,itemsep=0.1\baselineskip,leftmargin=!}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[comma,authoryear]{natbib}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References} 
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{\centering\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
```

I would prefer it if the rule length was this long (same width as the body)

[image: preferable]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put `\usepackage[margin=1.0in, headheight=30pt]{geometry} `  before `\usepackage{fancyhdr}`

Comment: worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!